# How to use formal limit definition?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

(a) IF $\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)=\infty$ THEN $\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \sin (f(x))$ does not exist.

I know that this statement is false.

I will give a counterexample for this as just take $f(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor \pi$.
How to prove that using formal definition of limit that this example violate above statement.

Comment: Easy:  Show that with this example function, the limit of $\sin f(x)$ exists and  show that $\lim f(x)$ is $\infty$

Comment: You don't need to use the formal definition of a limit in this case: $\sin(f(x))$ is a constant function.

Answer (score 2):

If $\varepsilon>0$, take *any* $M>0$. Then$$x\geqslant M\implies\left\lvert\sin\bigl(f(x)\bigr)\right\rvert<\varepsilon.$$This is the same thing as asserting that the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin\bigl(f(x)\bigr)$ exists (and it is equal to $0$).

Comment: There is no such restriction.

Comment: Because $\sin\bigl(f(x)\bigr)=0$.

Comment: I am proving that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin\bigl(f(x)\bigr)=0$, which means that$$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists M>0):x\geqslant M\implies\left\lvert\sin\bigl(f(x)\bigr)\right\rvert<\varepsilon.$$There is no $\delta$ here.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\sin f(x)=0$ for all $x$, the usual definition of an $x\to\infty$ limit shows $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin f(x)=0$.